# How to change the writing direction to 'Right to Left' in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, arabic

I am writing Arabic in Eclipse so I need to change the direction of writing from 'Left to Right' to 'Right to Left'

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable bidirectional text direction.

As usual click Window >
     Preferences > General > Globalization > Enable bidirectional support

Answer (score 0):

A bidirectional language is one that can write either right to left or left to right based on context. Bidirectional text is supported throughout the platform. Eclipse will recognize Hebrew, Arabic, Farsi and Urdu as bidirectional by default

[Supporting bidirectional text](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/bidi.html)

Comment: He recognizes arabic but the writing is incorrect so I need the cursor the move to the right instead

Comment: Chances are you are using an old Eclipse version, which does not fully support that yet. Upgrade to a new version in that case.